# Why do I still see localhost certificate being used even when I redirect a custom url to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: macos, security, ssl, glassfish, certificate

I am on OSX and in my hosts file I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost     MacBook-Pro.local
127.0.0.1   innbound
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Please note I have added the following line:

```
127.0.0.1   innbound
```

I have also a certificate installed on my machine which is trusted for the dns entry "innbound".
[image]

I imported this certificate to keystore.jks in Glassfish, but when I visit "innbound" from my browser, I still see certificate for localhost being used:

[image]

How can I test this certificate from Glassfish with customising my local environment so that the browser actually checks for a certificate for the "innbound" address and not localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated your imported Certificate in your config? Have a look at: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9825//ssl-certificate-installation-on-a-glassfish-application-server (Headline: Editing http-listeners in the Glassfish Administration Console).

Comment: Thank you but this does not help me. When I enter "innbound" in that field, the page is not acecsible at all afterwards.

Comment: Is "innbound" your certificate’s alias value?

Comment: I do not think your answer is related to my question. My question is more about some configuration in osx, rather than Glassfish. But still thanks.

Comment: But your system doesn't manage the tls-certs of a webservice. Glassfish is the service which offers the certificate to your webbrowser. It seems to be that it offers the wrong cert. I think your OS configuration is correct.

Comment: ah I see.. I am trying but can not get this thing to work.. Whatever I do, glassfish still offers the "localhost" certificate, whereas I want to be able to make glassfish offer the "innbound" certificate I have..

Answer (score 0):

When importing your certificate in the Glassfish `keystore.jks`, try to use the alias `s1as`.

It should look similar to this:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias s1as -file /your_cert.pem -keystore /keystore.jks
```

Don't forget to insert the correct paths before executing the command.